# Stackoverflowexception - Unable to find out the cause

Tags: vb.net, synchronization, stack, overflow

Second question on here...

Basically I am having a problem with a Stackoverflow exception that is thrown in my program, and I literally have no idea on how to locate the cause..

I have a program which has a plugin system, and it's a program that utilizes TCP in order to send and receive data; Server-> Client. I am making a remote console plugin, and the problem occurs when I do the command 'tree'; the filesystem entries listing command. For the first few seconds everything goes alright; the commands are being outputted (sent from Client to server). The receiving packets event isn't thread safe, so in the API I've provided an invocation function (to invoke methods on the UI thread). So therefore on output, it will do the following:

```
    Public Sub ClientReadPacket(Sender As IClient, Pipename As String, Values As Object())
    Select Case DirectCast(Values(1), ConsoleCommands)
        Case ConsoleCommands.Output
            ServerGUI.Send(Sub() ConsoleOutput.AppendText(Values(2) & Environment.NewLine))
    End Select
End Sub
```

As you can see, the ServerGUI is an interface that I have provided for plugin development. And in the actual program - in the class that implements the GUI interface, I get a stackoverflow exception right here:

```
Private Sub ISend(del As System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback) Implements IGUI.Send
    UIThread.Send(del, Nothing) 
End Sub ' The break point is here; I assume that means that the exception ocurs in the line above.
```

The UIThread object is a synchronizationcontext of the main thread.

http://i.gyazo.com/870d9667f2272969b650cea836adca50.png

Update: So far I've narrowed it down to the following; it must be causing stackoverflow exception when calling SynchronizationContext.Send() too often, and the same happens when I rather use Invoke() in the plugin, it also gives a Stackoverflow exception.

I tried using asyncoperation, and this does not crash, but due to the fact that it's solely asynchronous is a problem, because my program becomes unresponsive when using Post(), because it continuously Posts (due to the fact that it will manage the next packet before the asyncoperation has posted.

Comment: Post the exception and part of the stack trace.

Comment: Part of the stack trace, how do I do that?

Comment: `Private Sub ISend...Implements IGUI.Send` calls `UIThread.Send`  looks like that method is calling itself, calling itself, calling itself, calling itself...

Comment: An exception has a member called `StackTrace`

Comment: @Plutonix - What do you mean? - No, the method simply has the same name as in the SynchronizationContext.

Comment: @Alex - I can't seem to locate the StackTrace...

Comment: set a breakpoint on `UIThread.Send` let it run 2-3 times then open the Stack trace (Debug -> Windows -> Stack Trace ... maybe Ctrl-L).  You'll see the cause, but if you have a sub with one line of code and it is causing StackOverflow, it seems pretty clear who the culprit is, especially with the names.  Just as easy, step thru and see where it goes from there.

Comment: @Plutonix - Look, it keeps running for a good amount of times, and only suddenly it happesn; that being I assume that it isn't the method name.
GIF: http://i.imgur.com/RohoJdM.gif

Comment: @Prionum You can assume whatever you want. I assume your program runs fine, because you got advice and instructions on what to do, and I am sure that if you were smart you followed that advice.

Comment: @Alex - Mind elaborating on that?`- How does it randomly execute the wrong method (if that is what you're implying)?

Comment: I added an update to the OP.